# rails combine parameters in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, controller

Hopefully this is a little clearer. I'm sorry but I'm very new to coding in general. I have multiple tables that I have to query in succession in order to get to the correct array that I need. The following logic for the query is as follows:

this gives me an array based upon the store :id

```
store = Stores.find(params[:id])
```

this gives me another array based upon the param .location found in the table store where that value equals the row ID in the table Departments

```
department = Departments.find(store.location)
```

I need to preform one last query but in order to do so I need to figure out which day of the meeting is needed. In order to do this I have to create the parameter day_of_meeting found in the table Stores. I try to call it from the array above and create a new variable. In the Table Departments, I there are params such as day_1, day_2 and so on. I need to be able to call something like department.day_1 or department.day_2. Thus, I'm trying to actually create the variable by join the words "department.day_" to the variable store.day_of_meeting which would equal some integer, creating department.day_1...

```
which_day = ["department.day_", store.day_of_meeting].join("")
```

This query finds uses the value found from the variable department.day_1 to query table Meeting to find the values in the corresponding row.

```
meeting = Meeting.find(which_day)
```

Does this make my problem any clearer to understand?

Comment: You should do it in model.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how I can define that logic in the model?

Comment: I read your question over and over and I'm not even sure if I understand what you mean at all (it makes no sense to me) but since you don't use `params` a single time but make heavy use of object (model) attributes I guess controller is a wrong place to put it. Again, I think I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I re-wrote the question so hopefully it is a little clearer. Does it make any sense?

Comment: when you say `this gives me an array...`. You're wrong, `Stores.find(your_id)` is an `ActiveRecord` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find`method can only accept parameters like Meeting.find(1) or Meeting.find("1-xx").

so, what you need is `Meeting.find(department.send("day_" + store.day_of_meeting.to_s))`

Hope to help!

Comment: I get "no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String". The value is an integer so does it have to do with adding the text "day_" + the inetger (store.day_of_meeting)?

Comment: that is because store.day_of_meeting return integer, so need to convert it to string, i have updated!

Comment: perfect. thank you. I kept using .to_i - dumb on my part